# itunesconnect - reuse app name

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have two developer account. I created app from first developer account with certain name. App is not yet submitted for review, it is in initial development phase.

Now we thought creating app from another developer account will be more appropriate. Problem is that, now it is not allowing me to use the same name. It says "The App Name you entered has already been used". Which is fine, because it is used in another account.

But I went ahead and renamed my app from earlier account. Still it is not allowing me to use original name from second developer account.

1) Does it take some time to put app name back into pool? 
2) I don't see the delete option in the first dev account, so that I can try to delete the app.

Comment: Do you still need help, or any further elaboration or have we solved your question?

Answer (score 2):

If renaming the previous app to something completely random does not work, you can try this:

When you create the new app, instead of selecting "English" as primary language, select "UK English" (or anything else, really). The unicity is per language, and local variations are counted as separate languages.

Answer (score 1):

First off, once you register the app name, no matter if in development or release, that App name will from now on be taken. Now to your question, you have two options here. 
A) You could transfer the app to your second account 
B) You could delete the app (not recommended)

A) If you transfer the app, you basically give the ownership to another account. To do this, simply follow the steps listed by apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html).

B) This option is not recommended as once you remove it in this account you will never be able to reuse the identifier or the App name. If you want to go ahead and delete the app, follow this [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) again provided by Apple.

Lastly, you can try to simply rename your app. I am not sure if that will work as I have never tried it myself, but nothing speaks against it. Simply open your app in iTunes Connect and then change the display name. This should again offer the old name into the pool of available names. 
 Hope that helps, Julian

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the app actually worked for me:

1. Go to your iTunes connect account that contains the app you want to 'deprecate'
2. Select the app, go to App Information
3. Rename the app in Localizable Information, click save

Now sign into your other iTunes connect account and try to create the app.